# How to render "Where does that leave me" into French

Tags: expressions

> It was weeks before I learned the ropes–and now that tenderfoot has done the same thing in a matter of days! **Where does that leave me**, hm!?

To express this idea  in French, in conversation I said jokingly:

> Il m'a fallu des semaines pour prendre le pli... et voilà le blanc-bec qui y parvient en seulement quelques jours ! **Je ne sais pas quoi en penser** ?!

This colloquial, rhetorical English phrasing is essentially used to say:

- *I feel as if I've been overshadowed by a novice, **which puts me in an unfavourable light**.*

How is this idea effectively expressed in French?

Answer (score 4):

When you want to convey the idea of being overshadowed, you can say:

> J'ai l'air de quoi, moi, maintenant ?!

It means that you look bad compared to the other person, but also that you feel kind of ashamed because of that. When with a friend, a common answer (meant to tease) to that rhetorical question is: "*... d'un idiot, pardi !*" :)

Answer (score 1):

On peut insister sur le syllogisme sous-jacent (*un novice y arrive ; or je n'y arrive pas ; donc je suis encore moins capable qu'un novice*) comme ceci :

> Ça m'a pris des semaines d'apprendre le métier — et voilà que ce blanc-bec y parvient en quelques jours! **Qu'est-ce que je suis censé en conclure**, hein ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say like that :

**- Et moi, dans tout ça?**

**- Où est-ce que ça m'amène?! Hein?**

**- Où cela me mène-t-il ?**

**- Quel est le sens de tout ça?!**